# I am getting cannot find -lippicv in qt with opencv

Tags: c++, qt, opencv, cmake

I am working on qt with opencv. While building  my project, I get this error:

> cannot find -lippicv

Comment: [Similar question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/720528/opencv-compiling-error-ippicv) on askubuntu.