# qt "error: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status" and "error: cannot find -lippicv"

Tags: c++, qt

I try to compile this code but I get errors. I don't understand what is the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello World" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The error message you shared in the title says a library called -picv can not be found. Are you trying to work with openCV? Can you please share your .pro file

Comment: yes i am using opencv

Comment: can you share your email adres to send .pro file

Comment: Edit the question and add the .pro file contents there.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I am getting cannot find -lippicv in qt with opencv](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40329613/i-am-getting-cannot-find-lippicv-in-qt-with-opencv)

Comment: thank yo everbody i solved problem.

Comment: Fixed grammar and alignment a bit.

Comment: sorry for my english.